# What is more efficient StringBuffer new() or delete(0, sb.length())?

Tags: java, instance, stringbuffer, performance

It is often argued that avoiding creating objects (especially in loops) is considered good practice.

Then, what is most efficient regarding `StringBuffer`?

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
ObjectInputStream ois = ...;

for (int i=0;i<1000;i++) {

    for (j=0;i<10;j++) {
        sb.append(ois.readUTF());
    }
    ...

    // Which option is the most efficient? 
    sb = new StringBuffer(); // new StringBuffer instance?
    sb.delete(0,sb.length()); // or deleting content?

}
```

I mean, one could argue that creating an object is faster then looping through an array.

Comment: Have you tested it in a profiler? What were the results?

Comment: See also http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/7575/reusing-stringbuilder-or-creating-a-new-one

Answer (score 17, accepted):

First `StringBuffer` is thread-safe which will have bad performance compared to `StringBuilder`. StringBuilder is not thread safe but as a result is faster. Finally, I prefer just setting the length to 0 using [setLength](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#setLength%28int%29).

```
sb.setLength(0)
```

This is similar to `.delete(...)` except you don't really care about the length. Also probably a little faster since it doesn't need to '*delete*' anything. Creating a new `StringBuilder` (or StringBuffer) would be less efficient. Any time you see `new` Java is creating a new object and placing that on the heap.

**Note**: After looking at the implementation of `.delete` and `.setLength`, `.delete` sets length = 0, and `.setLength` sets every thing to `'\0'` So you may get a little win with `.delete`

Comment: If the `StringBuilder` gets a very large internal buffer allocated which is wasted because an early loop iteration produces a very large string, and later iterations don't, then you might end up thrashing longer than necessary, but otherwise keeping the buffer is a net win since if later iterations produce strings almost the same size as earlier iterations, you are avoiding some buffer copies.

Comment: `delete` is not O(N) when the delete clears the entire contents.

Comment: This is true, I am updating my answer. But only when len == count which is true if you are deleting all.

Comment: `setLength` will not sets everything to '\0'. Only if the new size is > to the current one and only for the part of the internal buffer that was extended.

Comment: Surprisingly, `StringBuilder.delete()` is 26% faster than `StringBuilder.setLength(0)` per JMH. It just goes to show you, you can't determine what's faster simply by looking at the code.

Answer (score 3):

Just to amplify the previous comments:

From looking at source, `delete`() always calls `System.arraycopy`(), but if the arguments are (0,count), it will call `arraycopy`() with a length of zero, which will presumably have no effect.  IMHO, this should be optimized out since I bet it's the most common case, but no matter.

With `setLength`(), on the other hand, the call will increase the StringBuilder's capacity if necessary via a call to `ensureCapacityInternal`()  (another very common case that should have been optimized out IMHO) and then truncates the length as `delete`() would have done.

Ultimately, both methods just wind up setting `count` to zero.

Neither call does any iterating in this case. Both make an unnecessary function call.  However ensureCapacityInternal() is a very simple private method, which invites the compiler to optimize it nearly out of existence so it's likely that `setLength`() is slightly more efficient.

I'm extremely skeptical that creating a new instance of StringBuilder could ever be as efficient as simply setting `count` to zero, but I suppose that the compiler *might* recognize the pattern involved and convert the repeated instantiations into repeated calls to `setLength`(0).  But at the very best, it would be a wash. And you're depending on the compiler to recognize the case.

Executive summary:  setLength(0) is the most efficient. For maximum efficiency, pre-allocate the buffer space in StringBuilder when you create it.

Answer (score 1):

The delete method is implemented this way:

```
public AbstractStringBuilder delete(int start, int end) {
    if (start < 0)
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(start);
    if (end > count)
        end = count;
    if (start > end)
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException();
    int len = end - start;
    if (len > 0) {
        System.arraycopy(value, start+len, value, start, count-end);
        count -= len;
    }
    return this;
}
```

As you can see it doesn't iterate through the array.

Comment: What do you think `System.arraycopy` does??

Comment: @Mike I am not sure what you mean `len` will be 0. It is computed from `end - start` which will `sb.length() - 0`. What you mean to say `count-end` will be 0 which is true. But generally you don't compute O(n) for only one set of params.

Comment: @Amir, sorry I think I was right about no significant work being done but I was wrong about why.  When `start` is 0 and `end` is `count` aka `this.length()`, then you end up doing `System.arraycopy(value, count, value, 0, 0)`.  The last 0 means it is copying 0 bytes from index count to index 0.

Comment: I've looked at the source code.  In this particular case, arraycopy() will do nothing but return.  All you've done is waste the overhead of a function call.